# Handle Not Set for a Named Pipe on WS 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, named-pipes

I have been unsuccessful in opening a Named Pipe on a
Windows Server 2008 R2 pre-production staging host and yet
I had no trouble at all developing that code on a development
WS 2008 R2 host (that should be configured identically)
and testing that pipe's operation.

The application has a WCF RESTful web service in IIS that
connects to a Windows Service via the Named Pipe. The
Windows Service then queries an Oracle DB via a Perl
script. But on the pre-production staging host we
never get that far because the pipe fails to open.

The first issue was an access violation. When I cured
that with a PipeSecurity instance I get a missing handle
exception. I do all work as Administrator on both of
the hosts. I've opened access on all related folders
on the pre-production host (yes, I'll secure it again
once it works). the IIS logs show nothing unusual about
the WCF service.

Here is the code from the development host that worked
"out of the box" with no issues.

```
ClientPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(
".", "QueryPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
TokenImpersonationLevel.None);

ClientPipe.Connect();
```

Simple and straight-forward.

Here is the code from the pre-production staging host
that I have endlessley tinkered with to try and get it
to work.

```
ClientPipe =
    new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "QueryPipe",
      PipeAccessRights.FullControl,
      PipeOptions.None,
      TokenImpersonationLevel.None,
      HandleInheritability.None);

PipeSecurity _ps = new PipeSecurity();

  _ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(
  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User,
    PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

_  ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(
    "SYSTEM", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

ClientPipe.SetAccessControl(_ps);

ClientPipe.Connect();
```

The use of the PipeSecurity class cured an initial problem
with access permissions (thanks to Chris Dickson's 2010 answer
about setting pipe access).

But after setting the Access Control I get this exception:

```
** Pipe Error: System.InvalidOperationException:
Pipe handle has not been set. 
Did your PipeStream implementation call InitializeHandle?
```

I have Googled until blue in the finger tips, but do not 
get a useful answer. It seems that I should already have
set a handle by merely using the constructor. InitializeHandle
should not apply here.

So, I look to your expertise in these matters.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that.  It was the *server* that called SetAccessControl(), making a list of the guests invited to the party.  You are not on it.  You can't put your own name on that list and get in the door that way.  You have to have an idea who's on that list so you can impersonate one of them.

Comment: ... or fix the code in the server.

Comment: My first chance to try your ideas will be tomorrow AM. But I am still puzzled as to why it all worked so nicely in development. It would seem that the two machines are not, as I had been told, configured identically.

Comment: Your poetic clues aimed me in the right direction and I finally found my solution in this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174660/namedpipeclientstream-can-not-access-to-namedpipeserverstream-under-session-0). As a noob I'm not sure how to mark one or both of you as "answer".

Answer (score 0):

It might have permission issue: So, need to provide required access rights.

```
PipeSecurity _pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
                PipeAccessRule psEveryone = new PipeAccessRule("Everyone", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);


           _pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(psEveryone);

            NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName,
                               PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 4, 4, _pipeSecurity);
```

And to overcome the problem of listening only once follow this setup: Right click on respective service > Properties > Log On > Log on as: Local System Account and tick Allow service to interact with desktop. Or go to ServiceProcessInstaller property and Set account as LocalSystem.