# IPC: UWP C# pipe client fails on connect C++ server

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, pipe, ipc

I am trying to use NamedPipe to communicate between app and service in Win10.  APP is developed with C#(UWP),running foreground as Pipe Client.  And service is C++ running background as Pipe Server.  Now the problem is that the APP couldn't connect the service. I know that MSFT doc said Pipes are only supported within an app-container. But I have tried the following cases: my uwp app VS C#(nonUWP) Server(not in an app-container); C++ Client VS C++ server(same code with service except running in foreground).  Both cases works fine.  So I think it may have something wrong with Security privilege.  But I couldn't find somthing abnormal, Could someone help me out?

**Client(UWP/C#):**

```
_namedPipeClientHandle[index] = CreateFileW(@"\\.\pipe\starpipe",
                            DESIREDACCESS.GENERIC_READ | DESIREDACCESS.GENERIC_WRITE,
                            SHAREMODE.FILE_SHARE_READ | SHAREMODE.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                            0,
                            CREATIONDISPOSITION.OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FLAGSANDATTRIBUTES.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            0);
                    if (_namedPipeClientHandle[index] != null && _namedPipeClientHandle[index].IsInvalid == false)
                    {
                        _namedPipeClientStream[index] = new FileStream(_namedPipeClientHandle[index], FileAccess.ReadWrite, 2048, true);
                        isConnected[index] = true;
                        break;
                    }
```

**Server(C++):**

```
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[2];
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pEveryoneSID)) return false;

    SecureZeroMemory(&ea, 2 * sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = FILE_ALL_ACCESS | GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ;
    ea[0].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
    ea[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
    ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pEveryoneSID;

    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pAdminSID)) return false;
    ea[1].grfAccessPermissions = FILE_ALL_ACCESS | GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ;
    ea[1].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
    ea[1].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
    ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
    ea[1].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pAdminSID;

    DWORD dwRes = SetEntriesInAclW(2, ea, NULL, &pACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) return false;

    auto secDesc = std::vector<unsigned char>(SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)(&secDesc[0]);
    if (nullptr == pSD) return false;

    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION)) return false;
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, TRUE, pACL, FALSE)) return false;

    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    const char* pStrPipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\starpipe";
    m_hPipe = CreateNamedPipeA(
        pStrPipeName,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        2048,
        2048,
        0,
        &sa);

    if (m_hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return false;

    if (::ConnectNamedPipe(m_hPipe, NULL)) return true;
```

Comment: You know that UWP is a nasty sandboxed environment?

Comment: yeah,I know UWP is nasty.But my uwp client could connect my C# pipe server now, i think it should be able to connect to my C++ pipe server.

Comment: What error do you get? What code do you use in your C# Server? This is not supported for various reasons even though you may get it to work for limited scenarios (like Enterprise sideloaded apps).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT CreateFileW return an invalid handle. C# Server is in https://github.com/vincent1000/RPC-Namedpipe

Answer (score 8):

when named pipe created from UWP process (appcontainer) name must have form

`"\\\\?\\pipe\\local\\SomeName"`

system convert this name to

`"\\\\?\\pipe\\Sessions\\<SessionId>\\AppContainerNamedObjects\\<AppContainerSid>\\SomeName"`

so desktop application must create pipe with such name format for UWP be able open it.
but for this need know appcontainer-sid for uwp app and it session id. ok, appcontainer-sid is permanent for concrete UWP - never changed, but SessionId can be different (usually 1 but can be and another). also need set special security descriptor on pipe, which grant access for `SDDL_EVERYONE + SDDL_ALL_APP_PACKAGES + SDDL_ML_LOW`. for example

`"D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AC)S:(ML;;;;;LW)"`

example of create such pipe in desktop

```
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

ULONG CreatePipeforUWP(OUT PHANDLE PipeHandle, PCWSTR PipeName, HANDLE hProcess)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), 0, FALSE };

    // SDDL_EVERYONE + SDDL_ALL_APP_PACKAGES + SDDL_ML_LOW
    if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
        L"D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AC)S:(ML;;;;;LW)", 
        SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, 0))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    HANDLE hToken;

    ULONG err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken));

    if (err == NOERROR)
    {
        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 128;

        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PTOKEN_APPCONTAINER_INFORMATION AppConainer;
            PWSTR sz;
        };

        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenAppContainerSid, buf, cb, &rcb));

            if (err == NOERROR)
            {
                ULONG SessionId;

                err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenSessionId, &SessionId, sizeof(SessionId), &rcb));

                if (err == NOERROR)
                {
                    PWSTR szSid;

                    err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(ConvertSidToStringSid(AppConainer->TokenAppContainer, &szSid));

                    if (err == NOERROR)
                    {
                        static const WCHAR fmt[] = L"\\\\?\\pipe\\Sessions\\%d\\AppContainerNamedObjects\\%s\\%s";

                        rcb = (1 + _scwprintf(fmt, SessionId, szSid, PipeName)) * sizeof(WCHAR);

                        if (cb < rcb)
                        {
                            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                        }

                        _swprintf(sz, fmt, SessionId, szSid, PipeName);

                        HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipeW(sz,
                            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_READMODE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT, 
                            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 0, 0, 0, &sa);

                        if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                        {
                            err = GetLastError();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            *PipeHandle = hPipe;
                        }

                        LocalFree(szSid);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        } while (err == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor);

    return err;
}

ULONG CreatePipeforUWP(OUT PHANDLE PipeHandle, PCWSTR PipeName, ULONG dwProcessId)
{
    if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, 0, dwProcessId))
    {
        ULONG err = CreatePipeforUWP(PipeHandle, PipeName, hProcess);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return err;
    }
    return GetLastError();
}


HANDLE hPipe;
if (CreatePipeforUWP(&hPipe, L"MyPipe", *) == NOERROR)
```

in client (UWP) app simply

```
CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\pipe\\local\\MyPipe", 
        FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
```

but for this server need know UWP session id (or process id) or assume that UWP run in same session with server. in general this is not nice.

i be advice use RPC instead named pipes. here no any problems.

desktop need use [`RpcServerRegisterIf3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-rpcserverregisterif3) and set SecurityDescriptor for interface for let UWP access it. say `"D:P(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AC)(A;;GA;;;S-1-15-2-2)S:(ML;;;;;LW)"`. and this fine work with UWP, for example server code

```
ULONG InitRpcServer()
{
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SecurityDescriptor;

    // generic all for SDDL_ALL_APP_PACKAGES + SDDL_EVERYONE

    ULONG dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
        L"D:P(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AC)(A;;GA;;;S-1-15-2-2)S:(ML;;;;;LW)", SDDL_REVISION, &SecurityDescriptor, 0));

    if (dwError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        dwError = RpcServerRegisterIf3(hello_v1_0_s_ifspec,
            NULL, NULL, RPC_IF_ALLOW_CALLBACKS_WITH_NO_AUTH,
            RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT, 0x10000, 0, SecurityDescriptor);

        if (dwError == RPC_S_OK)
        {
            dwError = RpcServerUseProtseqEpW(
                (RPC_WSTR)L"ncalrpc",
                RPC_C_PROTSEQ_MAX_REQS_DEFAULT,
                (RPC_WSTR)L"myname",
                SecurityDescriptor);

            if (dwError == RPC_S_OK)
            {
                dwError = RpcServerListen(1, RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT, TRUE);
            }
        }

        LocalFree(SecurityDescriptor);
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

and client only need

```
RpcBindingFromStringBinding((RPC_WSTR)L"ncalrpc:[myname]", &IDL_handle)
```

Comment: hmmm, it's a little complex than what i have thought. I will try your sample and update you. .

Comment: @vincent - yes, this complex. however better use rpc over ncalrpc - it much more easy to use

Comment: Since the server always runs before the client, how to detect the process ID of client? From your example, the entry is "if (CreatePipeforUWP(&hPipe, L"MyPipe", *) == NOERROR)", here '*' means processid of client, right? @RbMm

Comment: @vincent - no way take client process id in this case. you need use rpc over "ncalrpc"

Comment: Sorry for later update. I just have a baby. I have never used rpc before, so I do some search and set up a project with your code and have a try. It failed. Client always said it connected but server receive nothing. Could you take a look at it? It's a very simple project. https://github.com/vincent1000/RPC

Comment: i view in your c# rjl only RpcBindingFromStringBinding call. but i not view where you cal Hello

Comment: yeah, I am still looking for how to call Hello in C#. Since client/server stubs and header is generated into C/C++. Need I wrap them into a DLL so C# can call the interface?

Comment: @RbMm I tried your named pipe sample but I didn't use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag as I wanted `ConnectNamedPipe` to block the thread but instead `ConnectNamedPipe` returns nonzero value immediately. Any help regarding that??

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt - if you code correct, `ConnectNamedPipe` return nonzero value only after client connect (ie call `CreateFileW`)

Comment: Adding an ACE for `ALL_APP_PACKAGES` is too broad. You can use [`DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-deriveappcontainersidfromappcontainername) to get the SID without a handle to the process (e.g. if it's not running yet).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT - yes. possible do and this. i use more simply way, for get code smaller

Comment: @RbMm I use RPC in another project with your advice, it works well. Many thanks. I wonder whether those IPC methods such as shared memory, pipe, mutex etc don't adapt to this case. I have tried shared memory between uwp and win32 to exchange large mount of data, but failed.

Comment: @vincent *I have tried shared memory between uwp and win32 to exchange large mount of data, but failed.* - and what api call is failed ? with which error ?

Comment: @RbMm  In Server, I use CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile to create shared memory and in client, when I call OpenFileMapping, it gets access denied error. I verified the code in two win32 process, it works well.

Comment: @vicent but of course you must set security descriptor on section, which allow access from app container. Example of such sd in my answer

Comment: @RbMm yeah, but this also has the same issue you said before, we must know the SessionId while it will change each session, right?

Comment: @vincent no, this is related to named pipe only. But not to all objects. You got error access denied - this mean that object name is correct. Otherwise you got another error. Errors code s have sense but not random

Comment: @RbMm Got it. I will add security descriptor and have a try.

Comment: @RbMm After I set security descriptor, the shared memory works fine. Thanks for the great help. Back to the named pipe, you said that "system convert this name to
"\\\\?\\pipe\\Sessions\\<SessionId>\\AppContainerNamedObjects\\<AppContainerSid>\\SomeName"", How do you know this name? Does it exist in memory or register or other place?

Comment: @vincent NtQueryObject with ObjectNameInformation

Comment: @RbMm Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Any idea about this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358657/how-to-communicate-with-minifilter-driver-in-uwp

Comment: @vincent - idea is the same - need set security descriptor on CommunicationPort when you call `FltCreateCommunicationPort` which allow access for `S-1-15-2-2` and low integrity level

Comment: @RbMm I have already added the security descriptor. It still goes wrong with E_ACCESSDENIED.(I edit the link with latest code)

Comment: @vincent - what you do is absolute senseless. Security descriptor need add to object when you create but not open it. In kernel. So you not add security descriptor. For what you need all this at all ?

Comment: @RbMm I see. So the driver developer must add this security descriptor when he create this node in kernel.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> Pipes are only supported within an app-container; ie, from one UWP process to another UWP process that's part of the same app. Also, named pipes must use the syntax ".\pipe\LOCAL" for the pipe name.

Comment: But It works when communicating bewteen UWP pipe client and C#(non uwp) pipe server, they are not in same app. And when I try ".\pipe\Local", it goes wrong until i change it into "Local\pipe". This is not same what MSFT doc said.

Comment: "Supported" meaning they will work as you expect. They work outside of AC if the conditions are right.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT what are the conditions under which communication between uwp server and non-uwp client  works? I assume AC refers to ACL.

Comment: AC = AppContainer. You need to use the correct name AND have the correct ACL entries. And then you have to worry about things like suspended processes that will stall the pipe.