# How to communicate with minifilter driver in UWP?

Tags: uwp, driver, minifilter

I have a minifilter driver and want to connect it with FilterConnectCommunicationPort.
It works well in wpf, but it returns E_ACCESSDENIED in UWP even after I add SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES.

```
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SecurityDescriptor;
    bool ret = ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
        L"D:P(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AC)(A;;GA;;;S-1-15-2-2)S:(ML;;;;;LW)", 
    SDDL_REVISION, &SecurityDescriptor, 0);

    // Initialize a security attributes structure.
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = SecurityDescriptor;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    HRESULT hResult = S_OK;
    hResult = FilterConnectCommunicationPort(NPMINI_PORT_NAME, 0, NULL, 0, &sa, &g_hPort);
    if (IS_ERROR(hResult))
    {
        LogError("FilterConnectCommunicationPort fail! 0x%x",hResult);
        return hResult;
    }
```

I modify app package manifest to declare some restricted capabilities. Still not work.

```
<rescap:Capability Name="interopServices"/>
<iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices"/>
```

I am not sure whether FilterConnectCommunicationPort is allowed in UWP.If the api is ok, how to work with it? Thanks.

Comment: is it a windows IOT application?

Comment: @Anonymous No, it's just a voice changer app. And I want to capture audio and send it to virtual sound card driver after processed.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible in UWP, but since you've done it in WPF, why not use WPF instead.

Comment: @Anonymous I want it to be a widget, so it must be a uwp.

Comment: Does `FilterConnectCommunicationPort` need special privileges like administrator? If it is, then that should be the reason.

Comment: @Anonymous I have already run it with administrator. Maybe UWP prohibits to communicate with dirver like this.

Comment: I searched a bit. If you mean xbox bar widget, then you might be able to package the UWP app with a wpf app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/430792/packaging-project-with-xbox-game-bar-widget.html

Comment: @Anonymous Many thanks. That's what I will do. I divided it into a uwp and a background win32, but IPC between uwp and win32 is a little troube since uwp has some limitation to do it. Now I use RPC to realize it.  My plan is to use shared memory to handle it. No luck to succeed now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those capabilities. `interopServices` is a hold-out from the Windows Phone days, and `lowLevelDevices` only works on actual IOT (embedded-mode) OSes.

Adding the right ACE can be done with a function like this - just pass in the handle to your object, the PFN of the target app, and the desired access rights. (This hard-codes `SE_KERNEL_OBJECT` for simplicity; you might need to use a different [object type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/accctrl/ne-accctrl-se_object_type) depending on your needs).

```
bool GrantAccessToPackage(HANDLE handle, const wchar_t* packageName, DWORD accessRights)
{
  PSID packageSid{};

  if (!SUCCEEDED(DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName(packageName, &packageSid)))
  {
    throw std::exception("invalid pfn");
  }

  EXPLICIT_ACCESS explicitAccess{};
  explicitAccess.grfAccessMode = GRANT_ACCESS;
  explicitAccess.grfAccessPermissions = accessRights;
  explicitAccess.grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
  explicitAccess.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
  explicitAccess.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
  explicitAccess.Trustee.ptstrName = (LPWCH)packageSid;

  PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR securityDescriptor{ nullptr };
  PACL oldAcl{ nullptr };
  PACL newAcl{ nullptr };

  auto retVal = GetSecurityInfo(handle, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nullptr, nullptr, &oldAcl, nullptr, &securityDescriptor);
  if (SUCCEEDED(retVal))
  {
    retVal = SetEntriesInAclW(1, &explicitAccess, oldAcl, &newAcl);
    if (SUCCEEDED(retVal))
    {
      retVal = SetSecurityInfo(handle, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nullptr, nullptr, newAcl, nullptr);
    }
  }

  FreeSid(packageSid);
  if (securityDescriptor != nullptr)
  {
    LocalFree(securityDescriptor);
    if (newAcl != nullptr)
    {
      LocalFree(newAcl);

      // oldAcl is NOT freed; it's just a pointer into securityDescriptor
    }
  }

  return SUCCEEDED(retVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Security attributes for **FilterConnectCommunicationPort** is only used for inheritance purposes.
You must make sure the security descriptor you create in your filter is allowing access for you UWP application or better said the user under which your UWP is running is allowed to have access to your communication port.

If I remember correctly your UWP app should have its own SID. So in the filter when you call **FltCreateCommunicationPort** you must first have you ObjectAttributes parameter contain a SD which has an allowed ACE in the DACL for you UWP app SID.

You can use **RtlCreateSecurityDescriptor** (you must allocate first enough memory for you SD before calling this function), **RtlCreateAcl**, **RtlAddAccessAllowedAce**, **RtlSetDaclSecurityDescriptor** to create one and add you SID as an allowed ACE to your DACL in the SD.

Let me know if it works out for you.